# How do I access only specific elements that have a same class? jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, class

I am trying to create a shopping cart-like function that displays products found in a database and the user can select the quantity of each product and then add it to a cart. The problem that I am currently facing is that when the user clicks on a plus button, all the quantities change and they all display the clicked total price.
This is the code I have :

```js
$('.plus').bind('click', function(e) {
  $('.minus').prop('disabled', false)

  var quantity = parseInt($('.quantity').val());
  if (!isNaN(quantity) && quantity < 8) {
    $('.quantity').val(quantity + 1);
  } else if (quantity == 8) {
    $('.quantity').val(9);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
  }
  var price = parseFloat($('.price').text()).toFixed(2);

  if (quantity != 9) {
    if ((price * quantity) % 1 !== 0) {
      $(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * (quantity + 1)) + ".00");
    } else {
      $(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * (quantity + 1)) + "0");
    }
    $(".total_price").css("font-weight", "Bold");
    $(".total_price").css("color", "brown");
  } else {
    if ((price * quantity) % 1 !== 0) {
      $(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * 9) + ".00");
    } else {
      $(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * 9) + "0");
    }
    $(".total_price").css("font-weight", "Bold");
    $(".total_price").css("color", "brown");
  }
});

$('.minus').bind('click', function(e) {
  $('.plus').prop('disabled', false)

  var quantity = parseInt($('.quantity').val());
  if (!isNaN(quantity) && quantity > 1) {
    $('.quantity').val(quantity - 1);
  } else {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    $('.quantity').val(0);

  }
  var price = parseFloat($('.price').text()).toFixed(2);
  if ((price * quantity) % 1 !== 0) {
    $(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * (quantity - 1)) + ".00");
  } else {
    $(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * (quantity - 1)) + "0");
  }

  if (quantity != 1) {
    $(".total_price").css("font-weight", "Bold");
    $(".total_price").css("color", "brown");
  } else {

    $(".total_price").css("font-weight", "normal");
    $(".total_price").css("color", "black");
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row' id='product_item'>
  <div class='col-5' style='margin: auto;'>
    <input class='product_name' readonly type='text' name='product_name' style='display: inline; width:100%; border:white;' value='".$row[' productName ']."'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-1' style='margin: auto;'>
    <div class='price' style='display: inline;'>".$row['price']."</div>€</div>

  <div class='col-3' style='display:inline;  margin: auto;'>
    <div class='input_group_button'>
      <button class='btn plus' type='button'>
           <img src='img/plus.png'>
       </button>
    </div>
    <input class='input_group_field quantity' readonly type='number' name='quantity' value='0' max=9>
    <div class='input_group_button'>
      <button class='btn minus' type='button'>
         <img src='img/minus.png'>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-2' style='margin: auto;'><input class='total_price' readonly type='number' name='total_price' style='display: inline; width:65%; border:white;' value='0.00'>€</div>
  <div class='col-1'>
    <button class='btn' type='button' id='add_cart'>
     <img src='img/add-to-cart.png'>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Make a well-structured markup, with which you can rely on the order of the elements. Then use the `event` object passed to the handler function, get the clicked element from `event.target`, and traverse the wanted elements using the HTML structure, like target.prev(), target.parent().prev etc. to get the wanted elements to handle with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you can use the reference to the clicked element, using the `this` keyword in the event handler, to traverse the DOM to find the related elements using jQuery's built in methods such as `closest()` and `find()`.

In addition there's a couple of other things which can be addressed.

- `bind()` has been deprecated. Use `on()` instead.
- You can combine the `.minus` and `.plus` event handlers by using a `data` attribute on the buttons to determine which value should be added to the quantity. This reduces the amount of repetition in the code.
- You can use `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` to set the extents of the quantity field. This makes the code more succinct by removing the need for the lengthy `if` condition.
- Do not use `id` attributes in content which is repeated throughout the page. `id` *have* to be unique within the DOM. Use `class` attributes instead to group elements by behaviour.
- It's odd to use a block level `div` element and force it to be inline. If you want an inline element use on directly, such as a `span`.
- Avoid putting styling rules in your HTML. Put them in an external stylesheet.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$('.btn-inc').on('click', function(e) {
  let $el = $(this);
  let inc = $el.data('inc');
  $el.closest('.col-3').find('.quantity').val((i, v) => Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(v, 10) + inc, 0), 8));
  updatePrice();
});

let updatePrice = () => {
  $('.row').each((i, row) => {
    let $row = $(row);
    let $price = $row.find('.price');
    let $quantity = $row.find('.quantity');

    $row.find('.total_price').val(parseFloat($price.text() * $quantity.val()).toFixed(2));
  });
}
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
} 
.row > div margin: auto;

}
.row > .col-3 {
  display: inline;
}
input.product_name {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  border: white;
}
input.total_price {
  display: inline;
  width: 65%;
  border: white;
}
span.price {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- item 1 -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <input class="product_name" readonly type="text" name="product_name" value="productName">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <span class="price">1.00</span>€
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="input_group_button">
      <button class="btn plus btn-inc" type="button" data-inc="1">+</button>
    </div>
    <input class="input_group_field quantity" readonly type="number" name="quantity" value="0" max="9">
    <div class="input_group_button">
      <button class="btn minus btn-inc" type="button" data-inc="-1">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <input class="total_price" readonly type="number" name="total_price" value="0.00"> €
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button class="btn" type="button" class="add_cart">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- item 2 -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <input class="product_name" readonly type="text" name="product_name" value="productName">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <span class="price">9.99</span>€
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="input_group_button">
      <button class="btn plus btn-inc" type="button" data-inc="1">+</button>
    </div>
    <input class="input_group_field quantity" readonly type="number" name="quantity" value="0" max="9">
    <div class="input_group_button">
      <button class="btn minus btn-inc" type="button" data-inc="-1">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <input class="total_price" readonly type="number" name="total_price" value="0.00"> €
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button class="btn" type="button" class="add_cart">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks for making everything so clear!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I've taken your example and put together something which might be useful to you, here is the JSFiddle to be able to test it for yourself

https://jsfiddle.net/xsvg7t8L/

Here is the HTML, not how I have added an ID to each of the quantity fields and then an attribute to the plus and minus buttons which is the selector for the field we want to update.

```html
<div class='row' id='product_item'>
    <input id="quantity_1" class='input_group_field quantity' readonly type='number' name='quantity_1' value='0' max=9>
      <button class='btn plus' type='button' update="#quantity_1">
        +
      </button>
      <button class='btn minus' type='button' update="#quantity_1">
        -
      </button>
    </div>
<div class='row' id='product_item_2'>
      <input id="quantity_2" class='input_group_field quantity' readonly type='number' name='quantity' value='0' max=9>
      <button class='btn plus' type='button' update="#quantity_2">
        +
      </button>
      <button class='btn minus' type='button' update="#quantity_2">
        -
      </button>
</div>
```

Here is the JS, you can see I am getting the attribute using jQuery's attr() function and then using that to get the pointer to the quantity field rather than using the class.

```js
$('.plus').bind('click', function(e) {
  $('.minus').prop('disabled', false)
    // This attribute will contain the ID of the quantity you want to update
  var qtyField = $(this).attr('update');
  var quantity = parseInt($(qtyField).val());
  if (!isNaN(quantity) && quantity < 8) {
    $(qtyField).val(quantity + 1);
  } else if (quantity == 8) {
    $(qtyField).val(9);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
  }
});

$('.minus').bind('click', function(e) {
  $('.plus').prop('disabled', false)
  // This attribute will contain the ID of the quantity you want to update
  var qtyField = $(this).attr('update');
  var quantity = parseInt($(qtyField).val());
  if (!isNaN(quantity) && quantity > 1) {
    $(qtyField).val(quantity - 1);
  } else {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    $(qtyField).val(0);
  }
});
```

Not exactly what you asked for but hope it helps!

Comment: Please clarify why you think that statement is false? Using closest() and other similar methods is fine but the element that gets found completely depends on the layout of the markup so is not what I would class as 'finding an specific element', it's purely a technicality though and open to interpretation and in your example it works as expected (great answer by the way). The issue for me would be that if the markup changes you could potentially introduce bugs if you did not review and update the JS at the same time, if you use IDs you would reduce the likelihood of this issue.

Comment: I agree on that - my point is that your first statement about uniquely identifying the elements being the *only* way to do this is not correct. If you would remove that line I will happily remove the downvote as the answer itself has merit, although I'd suggest using `data-update` instead of creating a non-standard attribute.

Comment: I've removed that comment, in hindsight I can see how that could be confusing for someone reading it without further explanation, it's actually the first answer I've ever posted on here so it's something for me to work on for sure, thanks for the feedback! And yes good suggestion on using that attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong.

Think about it, you have a List of `product_item` then when you click on plus or minus then you need those values that are under this specific `product_item` right?

Ok lets see what we can do about your code and make a small change that will fix the issue.

```js
$('.plus').bind('click', function(e) {
  var productItem = $(this).closest("#product_item")
  console.log(productItem.length)
  productItem.find('.minus').prop('disabled', false)
  var quantity = parseInt(productItem.find('.quantity').val());
  if (!isNaN(quantity) && quantity < 8) {
    productItem.find('.quantity').val(quantity + 1);
  } else if (quantity == 8) {
    productItem.find('.quantity').val(9);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
  }
  var price = parseFloat(productItem.find('.price').text()).toFixed(2);

  if (quantity != 9) {
    if ((price * quantity) % 1 !== 0) {
      productItem.find(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * (quantity + 1)) + ".00");
    } else {
      productItem.find(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * (quantity + 1)) + "0");
    }
    productItem.find(".total_price").css("font-weight", "Bold");
    productItem.find(".total_price").css("color", "brown");
  } else {
    if ((price * quantity) % 1 !== 0) {
      productItem.find(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * 9) + ".00");
    } else {
      productItem.find(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * 9) + "0");
    }
    productItem.find(".total_price").css("font-weight", "Bold");
    productItem.find(".total_price").css("color", "brown");
  }
});

$('.minus').bind('click', function(e) {

  var productItem = $(this).closest("#product_item")
  productItem.find('.plus').prop('disabled', false)
  var quantity = parseInt(productItem.find('.quantity').val());
  if (!isNaN(quantity) && quantity > 1) {
    productItem.find('.quantity').val(quantity - 1);
  } else {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    productItem.find('.quantity').val(0);

  }
  var price = parseFloat(productItem.find('.price').text()).toFixed(2);
  if ((price * quantity) % 1 !== 0) {
    productItem.find(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * (quantity - 1)) + ".00");
  } else {
    productItem.find(".total_price").val(parseFloat(price * (quantity - 1)) + "0");
  }

  if (quantity != 1) {
    productItem.find(".total_price").css("font-weight", "Bold");
    productItem.find(".total_price").css("color", "brown");
  } else {

    productItem.find(".total_price").css("font-weight", "normal");
    productItem.find(".total_price").css("color", "black");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row' id='product_item'>
  <div class='col-5' style='margin: auto;'>
    <input class='product_name' readonly type='text' name='product_name' style='display: inline; width:100%; border:white;' value='".$row[' productName ']."'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-1' style='margin: auto;'>
    <div class='price' style='display: inline;'>".$row['price']."</div>€</div>

  <div class='col-3' style='display:inline;  margin: auto;'>
    <div class='input_group_button'>
      <button class='btn plus' type='button'>
           <img src='img/plus.png'>
       </button>
    </div>
    <input class='input_group_field quantity' readonly type='number' name='quantity' value='0' max=9>
    <div class='input_group_button'>
      <button class='btn minus' type='button'>
         <img src='img/minus.png'>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-2' style='margin: auto;'><input class='total_price' readonly type='number' name='total_price' style='display: inline; width:65%; border:white;' value='0.00'>€</div>
  <div class='col-1'>
    <button class='btn' type='button' id='add_cart'>
     <img src='img/add-to-cart.png'>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```